# Как получить список всех сообщений в группе Telegram через Bot API?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Есть бот в Telegram, с помощью какого запроса можно получить список всех сообщений в группе или канале?

Как понимаю, запросы вида:

https://api.telegram.org/bot_token/getUpdates?chat_id=@chat

Позволяют получить только обновления, а как получить полный список постов используя только Bot API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В текущей реализации Bot API это невозможно. Однако, Вы можете попробовать делать это с помощью [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api#telegram-api) - метод [messages.getHistory](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory) подходит для описанной задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Bot API не имеет доступ к старым сообщениям, только Telegram API

Если бот администартор на канале или в группе, то он может ловить новые сообщения, и записывать их в БД

Если канал открыт, то можно тупо парсить его через web страницу его сообщения перебрав от последнего до самого первого,
https://t.me/LearnRubyForPikabu/128 где LearnRubyForPikabu как пример имени вашего открытого канала, а 128 номер сообщения на канале

Answer (score -1):

Для этого бота нужно сделать админом группы. Соответственно будет работать только в обычных группах. В супергруппах и каналах работать не будет. В супертгруппах точно. Для бота админа приходят в стандартных уведомлениях getUpdates все сообщения в группе.

Comment: Кажется, в вопросе идёт речь о ранее отправленных сообщениях. А не о приватном режиме, который можно отключить в настройках бота; правила приватного режима не действуют для ботов-админов не зависимо от типа группы и активации этого режима у @BotFather.